# Get all possible combinations of characters in list

Tags: python

I have a list `[".","_","<<",">>"]`

What i need is to get all strings with length of 4 with all possible combinations where each character is one of the above list .

example : 
`"._<<>>","__<<>>",".<<<<>>" ... etc`

now i am doing it for length of 4 :

```
mylist = [".","_","<<",">>"]
for c1 in mylist:
    for c2 in mylist:
        for c3 in mylist:
            for c4 in mylist:
                print "".join([c1,c2,c3,c4])
```

but that looks ugly , and what if i need to scale it up to length of 10 or more ?

Comment: Amazing how often something in `itertools` is the answer to StackOverflow questions about Python. Maybe the web site should suggest "Did you check whether itertools can help?" when asking a Python question. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to generate the combinations for you, without nested loops:

```
from itertools import product

mylist = [".", "_", "<<", ">>"]
length = 4
for chars in product(mylist, repeat=length):
    print ''.join(chars)
```

Simply adjust the `length` variable to get longer combinations.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) for that purpose

```
n = 4
for symbols in itertools.product([".","_","<<",">>"], repeat=n):
    print "".join(symbols)
```

one-liner :

```
print "\n".join(["".join(s) for s in itertools.product([".","_","<<",">>"], repeat=n)])
```